# Defining an inner class using the Python C-API

Tags: python, python-c-api, setattribute, setattr, pyobject

In Python, it’s straightforward to define an inner class:

```py
class MyClass(object):

    class MyInnerClass(object):
        pass
```

… which the inner class can be accessed as one would expect, e.g. by doing `MyClass.MyInnerClass`.

I am trying to set up something similar with an extension module. Typically one adds the extension types one defines to the extension module object in the modules’ `<modulename>init()` function with code like this:

```cpp
/// …
if (PyType_Ready(&BufferModel_Type) < 0)      { return; }

/// Add the BufferModel type object to the module
Py_INCREF(&BufferModel_Type);
PyModule_AddObject(module,
    "Buffer",
    (PyObject*)&BufferModel_Type);

/// …
```

In order to set up the inner class, I varied this approach to try and add a `PyTypeObject*` as an attribute of another `PyTypeObject*`, like so:

```cpp
/// …
if (PyType_Ready(&ImageBufferModel_Type) < 0) { return; }
if (PyType_Ready(&ImageModel_Type) < 0)       { return; }

/// Add the ImageBufferModel type object to im.Image
Py_INCREF(&ImageBufferModel_Type);
PyObject_SetAttrString((PyObject*)&ImageModel_Type,
    "ImageBuffer",
    (PyObject*)&ImageBufferModel_Type);
PyType_Modified((PyTypeObject*)&ImageModel_Type);

/// Add the ImageModel type object to the module
Py_INCREF(&ImageModel_Type);
PyModule_AddObject(module,
    "Image",
    (PyObject*)&ImageModel_Type);

/// …
```

… I figured `PyObject_SetAttrString()` would work as the [introduction to “Type Objects” in the C-API docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/typeobj.html) specifically says:

> Type objects can be handled using any of the `PyObject_*()` or
>   `PyType_*()` functions […]

… and I added the call `PyType_Modified()` based on [its description in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/type.html#c.PyType_Modified). But so: when I compile everything and try to load the extension, I get this error:

```
>>> import im
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    import im
  File "im/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from im import (
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'im.Image'
```

… I presume I am going about this the wrong way; what should I try instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need to use [`tp_dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_dict) directly:

> This field should normally be initialized to *NULL* before `PyType_Ready` is called; it may also be initialized to a dictionary containing initial attributes for the type. Once `PyType_Ready()` has initialized the type, extra attributes for the type may be added to this dictionary only if they don’t correspond to overloaded operations (like `__add__()`).

Instead of using `PyObject_SetAttrString()` you could just do

```
PyDict_SetItemString(ImageModel_Type.tp_dict, "ImageBuffer", (PyObject*) &ImageModel_Type);
```

But in this case the warning from the documentation applies:

> It is not safe to use `PyDict_SetItem()` on or otherwise modify `tp_dict` with the dictionary C-API.

So maybe initialize the `tp_dict` before calling `PyType_Ready` on `ImageModel_Type`:

```c
/// Initialize tp_dict with empty dictionary
ImageModel_Type.tp_dict = PyDict_New();
if (!ImageModel_Type.tp_dict) { return; }

/// Add the ImageBufferModel type object to im.Image
if (PyType_Ready(&ImageBufferModel_Type) < 0) { return; }
Py_INCREF(&ImageBufferModel_Type);
PyDict_SetItemString(ImageModel_Type.tp_dict,
    "ImageBuffer",
    (PyObject*)&ImageBufferModel_Type);

/// Add the ImageModel type object to the module
if (PyType_Ready(&ImageModel_Type) < 0) { return; }
Py_INCREF(&ImageModel_Type);
PyModule_AddObject(module,
    "Image",
    (PyObject*)&ImageModel_Type);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! The type object documentation is sometimes confusing and I appreciate this direct answer, this totally works.

Comment: I should also add that making changes to a PyTypeObject’s `tp_dict` data member can be used to achieve many of the same ends often achieved with metaclasses, on the Python side (e.g. synthesizing class-based descriptors á la Django’s ORM, et cetera).